# how to remove a backup of a purchased app

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, applications, backup

I have a certain app installed on my iPhone 6 Plus device.

Due to some technical issues with this app, I need to completely remove it from the device and re-install it.

Although it seems like I can remove it from the device itself (long-tap and clicking on the "x" icon at the corner), when I go to the App Store, I get this app downloaded from iCloud and not really fully re-installed and still holds all the settings and data in the app.

I need to know how to completely remove this app from my device AND account, so it can be re-installed from fresh.

Thanks in advance for any help in this matter.

Comment: There are various ways how an application can preserve state even if it is removed from the device. Which specific app are you talking about? Does it use iCloud or any other cloud service for storage? Do you need to log into something to use it?

Comment: Some applications when deleted have a prompt to keep settings or to delete the settings. You did fully delete the app, though your Data (Settings and stuff) are still stored on iCloud. So delete them.